# hive regexp_extract after second occurrence of delimiter

Tags: hive

we have a Hive table column which has string separated by ';' and we need to extract the string after second occurrence of ';'

```
+-----------------+
| col1            |
+-----------------+
| a;b;c;d         |
| e;f; ;h         |
| i;j;k;l         |  
+-----------------+

Required output:

+-----------+
| col1      |
+-----------+
| c         |
| <null>    |
| k         |  
+-----------+
```

select  regexp_extract

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the string on `;` which will return an array of values and from this you can get the element at index 2.

```
select split(str,';')[2]
from tbl
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert empty and space-only strings to NULLs like in your example, then this macro can be useful:

```
create temporary macro empty_to_null(s string) case when trim(s)!='' then s end;
select empty_to_null(split(col1,'\\;')[2]);
```